# Generic type requires 1 type argument(s) error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an abstract class like:

```
export abstract class CsvFileReader<T> {
  data: T[] = []

  constructor(public file: string) {}

  abstract mapRow(row: string[]): T

  read() {
    this.data = this.file
      .split('\n')
      .map((row: string): string[] => {
        return row.split(',')
      })
      .map(this.mapRow)
  }
}
```

and a class that extends above abstract class:

```
type matchData = [Date, string, string, number, number, MatchResualts, string]

export class MatchReader extends CsvFileReader<matchData> {
  mapRow(row: string[]): matchData {
    return [
      dateStringToDate(row[0]),
      row[1],
      row[2],
      +row[3],
      +row[4],
      row[5] as MatchResualts,
      row[6],
    ]
  }
}
```

I create reader just like this:

```
const reader = new MatchReader(Matches)
```

but i get this error: **Generic type 'CsvFileReader' requires 1 type argument(s).**

any solution?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but I put your code (only without the `export`s and without the unknown `dateStringToDate` and `MatchResualts` items, and with dummy file contents) into the TypeScript Playground and then it compiles and runs without a problem. Here is the code that I used: https://pastebin.com/5xFBfedZ

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my first answer was wrong.

you need to do something like this: `const reader: CsvFileReader<matchData> = new MatchReader(Matches)`

Does this work?